# Sanitizing `wp_editor();` Values for Database, Edit, and Display

Tags: posts, custom-field, database, post-meta, sanitization

I'm using custom instances of `wp_editor();` to allow rich text editing of Post Meta associated with a Post Object.

I'd like to perform much of the same sanitization that occurs with `post_content` for the values of these fields.

**Here's what I've come up with:**

> Please let me know if this is an okay approach, or if there is more I
>   should be doing in either of these three steps, or if there's a better
>   or easier way.

**On `save_post`:**

```
$value = wp_filter_post_kses( sanitize_post_field( 'post_content', $value, 0, 'db' ) );
```

**Passing Value to `wp_editor();`:**

```
$value = wp_unslash( sanitize_post_field( 'post_content', $value, 0, 'edit' ) );
```

**Outputting Value on Frontend:**

```
$value = wp_unslash( sanitize_post_field( 'post_content', $value, 0, 'display' ) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_kses` to the rescue!

### My Editor Contains everything a Post Might

Pass the result through `wp_kses_post` on the way in and out, and all should be good.

Remember, this will strip out anything added by `the_content` filter, so to preserve oembeds and shortcodes, use this:

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', wp_kses_post( $content ) );
```

You might also want `esc_textarea` for outputting the form if you're using `<textarea>` tags directly

### My Editor contains text, but no markup

On output, `esc_html` is your friend. Use this for situations when you have a text area that will never contain markup. On input, try `wp_strip_all_tags` on input to sanitise. The other WP APIs will make sure no SQL injections occur

### My Editor contains markup, but a limited subset

`wp_kses` to the rescue, pass it through `wp_kses` along with a second parameter, an array defining what tags and attributes are allowed. E.g.:

```
$allowed = [
    'a' => [
        'href' => [],
        'title' => []
    ],
    'br' => [],
    'em' => [],
    'strong' => [],
];

echo wp_kses( $content, $allowed );
```

Be wary though of overextending. If you add script and iframe tags, is there really any point in using `wp_kses`?

### wp_editor

`wp_editor` outputs internally, it can't be escaped, therefore it is responsible for escaping itself. Do not try to be unhelpful by passing it pre-escaped content, this can lead ot mangled output and double escaping ( a great way for malformed content to bypass escaping ).

The function that outputs has the responsibility for escaping. This enables late escaping. Escaping earlier or multiple times is dangerous and introduces new complex problems, as you no longer know with certainty what is or isn't escaped.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track.

The [`sanitize_post_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_post_field/) function calls the [`content_save_pre`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/post.php#L2060) hook which, when given the DB context, will also call the [`wp_filter_post_kses` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/kses_init_filters/) so there's no need to wrap it/call it again.

As far as I can tell at this point once it's been saved to the database we don't need to unslash anything for display. Here's what I have which is fairly similar to what you already had:

**Saving Value**

```
update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_test', sanitize_post_field( 'post_content', $_POST['_test'], $post->ID, 'db' ) );
```

**Passing Value**

```
$editor_content = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_test', true );

wp_editor( $editor_content, 'editor_id_here', array(
    'textarea_name' => '_test',
) );
```

**Displaying Value**

```
$editor_content     = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_test', true );
$display_content    = apply_filters( 'the_content', $display_content );
```